# systemd sends SIGTERM twice when stopping a service

Tags: systemd, signals

I have a C++ program that is being called by a systemd service. The program is not immediately called, but is nested in other scripts that are detached with '&'.

When I stop the service the program receives very quickly SIGTERM twice. I taught that SIGTERM should be sent only once.

If I start the script chain without a service in a separate process group, when I kill the group, the program receives the signal only once as expected. This should rule out that something in the scripts is causing the multiple signals.

If instead of a native program I have a bash script that uses `trap ... SIGTERM`, the signal is received only once. Weird.

What could be causing the multiple signals?

Comment: I see the same. Infact when I use systemd to close down my apps I am even seeing 3 SIGTERMS - around 500ms aprt. I don;t really want that behaviour - but I think it is normal. I am just starting my search to see if I can change this... did you find anything?

Comment: @code_fodder, I change the behavior of the application not to rely on a single SIGTERM. If you can back up your comment with some reference, that sending multiple signals is by design, I would accept such an answer.